# What is the best practice for open a new page or redirect page in GWT?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

There are some options to open a new page or redirect page in GWT, & I don't know which one is the best?

-Option 1: will redirect the current page to a new page but not opening a new tab.

```
String url = Window.Location.createUrlBuilder().setHash("!search").buildString();
Window.Location.assign(url);
```

-Option 2: open a new page on a new tab.

```
String url = Window.Location.createUrlBuilder().setHash("!search").buildString();
Window.open(url, "_blank", null);
```

-Option 3: will redirect the current page to a new page but not opening a new tab & retain the states of the previous page

```
PlaceRequest request=new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.search);
placeManager.revealPlace(request);
```

In Option 1 & 2, it seems that the system starts to reload the whole page. For option 2, if you press `Back` button then it will reload the previous page again.

In Option 3, it seems that it does not reload the whole page (ie if you have a header then it won't download the header again). Therefore, it run very fast. If you click `Back` button then it won't reload the previous page so you can still see all the existing states of the previous page.

Option 3 is quite fast. However, we need to properly reset some variables in the previous page otherwise it will make thing really messy and error-prone.

What is the best practice for open a new page or redirect page in GWT? Which option should we use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1

Whenever you reload the page, your app has to reload as well. It may happen fast, as the browser caches your code and other static elements, but what is the point? GWT is  used as an "app": it resides within a single host page, and changes its state based on user instructions.

`Window.Location.assign(url)` is only used when a user is leaving your application: either because this user logged out, or because he is not logged in yet, and you redirect him to a login page.

Option 2

Usually, this option is used when you provide a link to a different application/website, and you want to keep your app running.

Option 3

In this option you do not "redirect" "pages". You show different "views" to a user. The web page (host page) remains the same at all times. This is how GWT is supposed to work.

Comment: so option 3 is NOT for "redirect" so when we should use it? You mean we should use option3 all the time & option1 only when user logout? For option3, we need to be very carefully about the cope of the variables otherwise it gonna be messed up. don't we?

Comment: I suggest that you read Activities and Places design pattern for GWT. It explains how a user can navigate from one "place" to another within a GWT application: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html

Comment: MVP can be done without using Activities and Places. Using the GWTP framework you should be using option 3 for pretty much everything.